# Does any one no how to get value from one haskell program to another

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am a newbie to function programming. How can I pass a value from one Haskell program to another? Suppose we have

- in a file called `Addition.hs`:

  ```
  Addition::Int
  Addition = value+10
  ```
- in a file called `Value.hs`:

  ```
  value::Int
  value=20
  ```

With PHP, for example, if include a  file in another, I can access its classes. Is it possible in Haskell? That would make my program clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference members of other modules if you import that module, and the module exports the member:

Value.hs

```
module Value ( value ) where

value :: Int
value = 20
```

Addition.hs

```
module Addition ( addition ) where

import Value

addition :: Int
addition = value + 10
```

Comment: Thank you so much, It worked and full-filled my need :)

Comment: Glad to hear it, please mark the asnwer as an accepted solution if it solved your problem :)

Comment: it says can not find module 'Value' 

Both the files are in same folder on my desktop. Is there any other place that i have to put them

Comment: are you trying to compile the modules or load them in Prelude? what exact command are you typing and what is the exace error message?

Comment: What i am trying to do is if i run Addition.hs and type addition on GHCI command line it simply returns the answer

Comment: Is this not what you wanted? You defined `addition` as an `Int`, did you mean for it to be a function?

Comment: This is what i wanted but I don't know how can i use module in function ? 
I want a function to use a module

Comment: modules exist in a larger scope. modules conatin functions. functions in a given module can reference functions and values in other moduels referenced by that module. you can't reference a module in a local function scope though.